# Twilio: statusCallBack?

Tags: twilio, crm

Need some Twilio help. I am a novice and I'm kinda lost. This may seem overly simplistic BUT I have a CRM client that will track calls as long as the inbound calls ping the URL - `x2vps.com/index.php/api/voip/data/{caller id goes here}`

**Note:** The CRM will automatically track all registered phone numbers that ping this URL.

I have the call routing piece figured out. I can't figure out how to code twilio's API to append the inbound caller ID's to the CRM's URL and ping it. I want to log all calls regardless of the status.

If you could point me in the right direction I would be truly appreciative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio does not append the caller ID to the webhook URL that you set. In order to do something like this, you'd need to provide some sort of server in the middle that can transform the Twilio request into the format you need.

You'd do this by creating a web application that would be able to receive the webhook from Twilio. It would then need to get the incoming Caller ID from the Twilio request, this is the `From` parameter. With the Caller ID, your application would then construct your CRM endpoint URL and make the HTTP request itself. You'd need to decide whether you need to include all the original parameters, if the CRM system can use them.

Let me know if this helps.